# how can I specify the lifetimeof a fully contained struct in rust with no cicular deps

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a struct that contains a list of other structs, (could be fixed size if that helped)

```
struct Container<'m> {
    contained: Vec<&'m Contained>,
}

struct Contained {
    id: u64,
}

impl Container<'_> {

    pub fn new<'m>() -> Container<'m> {
        Container {
            contained: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn new_contained<'m>(&mut self, id: u64) {
        let c = Contained {
            id
        };
        self.contained.push(&c);
                            ^^ lifetime of Contained ends here
    }
}
```

I can see that life time of Contained ends but I cant see how to create a struct with a given lifetime.

Do I have any alternatives I tried using a fixed size array instead of a Vec this way the Container owns the contents of the Array, but I cant create a zero sized array to start with.

Comment: Why does your `Vec` contain references to `Contained`? Simply `contained: Vec<Contained>` should suffice for most use cases.

Comment: Please explain your requirements. In other words, what are you trying to achieve? Where are your `Contained` objects? They have to live somewhere else that outlives the `Container`.

Comment: I specifically dont want Cobntained to outlive Container.  I wou8ld like objects with the same life time, and I need to reference with pointers &Contained because otherwise I get size not know during complication errors.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question , it seem Box does what I want

```
struct Container {
    contained: Box<Option<Contained>>
}

struct Contained {
    id: u64,
}

impl Container {

    pub fn new() -> Container {
        Container {
            contained: Box::new(None),
        }
    }

    pub fn new_contained(&mut self, id: u64) {
        let c= Contained {
            id
        };
        self.contained = Box::new(Some(c));
    }
}
```

Contained appears to live the same lifetime as Container.

Comment: _"Contained appears to live the same lifetime as Container"_  — When `Container` is dropped it will drop the `Box` which will, in turn, drop its contents.